# Checking a massive list of strings for uniqueness

Tags: list, algorithm, performance, unique

I have a massive list of strings. Each string is relatively short, maybe around 64 characters, but the entire list takes about 8GB of disk space. I need to programmatically test whether this list contains any duplicate strings, and, ideally, output all the duplicates; and I need to do this as quickly as possible.

The usual solution of loading all the strings into a hashtable/HashSet/Dictionary obviously wouldn't work, because I can't afford to waste 8GB of RAM (and it wouldn't work anyway since there's likely no contiguous chunk long enough). Is there some smarter algorithm that I can use ? I expect this list to contain only unique strings most of the time, so perhaps I can use a Bloom Filter as the first pass; but in the event of a collision, I still need to find the actual duplicates.

Comment: How much RAM do you have? Store the hashes into buckets, so that the size of one bucket you can afford.

Comment: [External sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting)

Comment: You could do two passes: one to generate the Bloom filter and one to process the collisions.

Comment: @stark You should make an answer out of your comment. Sounds like a very good solution candidate.

Comment: @stark: yes, but this is basically the process I'm using already. As I said in the last sentence of my post, if the Bloom filter reports a collision, I have no choice but to execute a second pass.

Answer (score 0):

If the strings are somewhat similar a [ternary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search_tree) could limit the memory needed and easily detect duplicate at insertion

Comment: This is a good idea, but unfortunately I cannot guarantee that the strings will be similar. However, I might be able to detect edge cases (based on other metadata) when they will be, so for these cases I could use a ternary search tree.